# Javaprogram doesn't realize I'm returning a boolean

Tags: java

I'm working on a program which is supposed to create a lot of particles moving around, when they get close to the "wall", which is simply the edge of my JFrame, they are supposed to get stuck.

So far so good, this is actually working, but now I want to implement so that particles close to other particles that's already been stuck gets stuck as well.
I'm not gonna provide any details in these matter because I think my problem is more basic than this.

See code below:

```
    public void updatePos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofparticles; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j< numberofparticles; j++) {
            if (particlelist.get(i).isStuck())  {
                continue;
            if (particlelist.get(i).isClose(particlelist.get(j))) {
                continue;
            particlelist.get(i).x += getL()*Math.cos(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
            particlelist.get(i).y += getL()*Math.sin(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
        }
        }
            }
        }
    }

        public void isClose(Particle p) {
            if (Math.sqrt(getX()*getX() +getY()*getY())-Math.sqrt(p.getX()*p.getX() +p.getY()*p.getY())<=2)  {
                isStuck();}
        }


    }
}

public boolean isStuck() {
        if (this.x>=610) {
            setX(610);
            return true;}
        else if (this.x<=5) {
            setX(5);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.y<=5) {
            setY(5);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.y>=610) {
            setY(610);
            return true;}
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is that my first method, the public void updatePos(), the line where is says:

```
if (particlelist.get(i).isClose(particlelist.get(j))) {
```

My program doesnt understand that isClose is actually making a call to isStuck(), which should return a boolean, therefore I'm getting the error:

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean"

Can I change my method to make my program realize that what I get back is actually a boolean?

Comment: You "call" `isStuck`, but you doesn't actually "return".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your method as per below

```
public boolean isClose(Particle p) {
    if (Math.sqrt(getX()*getX() +getY()*getY())-Math.sqrt(p.getX()*p.getX() +p.getY()*p.getY())<=2)  {
            return isStuck();
        }
    return <default value>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `return` keyword to **return a value** from a method as shown below:

```
public boolean isClose(Particle p) {
  if (Math.sqrt(getX()*getX() + getY()*getY())-Math.sqrt(p.getX()*p.getX() + 
                   p.getY()*p.getY())<=2)  {
     return isStuck();
  } else {
     return false;//default case
  }
}
```

Also, your method `isClose()` needs to tell that it returns `boolean` by changing from `void` to boolean (shown above).